# How to track change(Update/delete) in MYSQL for later query (NOT FOR LOG)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have research some question in stackoverflow, but what I want is for later query purpose, not for logging purose.

I have a project that needs to get value from certain moment.
For example
I have a user table

```
User:
id
name
address

Pet:
id
name
type

Adoption:
id
user_id
pet_id
```

Data:

```
User:
1, John, One Street
Pet:
1, Lucy, Cat
Adoption:
1, 1, 1
```

Let's say the user change address so it look like

```
User:
1, John, Another Street
```

And what I need is
**What is the address(or other field)** of the user **when they adopt** the pet.

What I am thinking of is always create a new row in same table(in this case user) and refer the new row to the previous row

```
User:
2, 1, John, Another Street ( where 1 is referring to the previous id / updated from)
1, NULL, John, One Street, deleted (NULL means this is newly created data)
```

The advantage of using this is, it's easy to query(I just query like usual
The downside is the table will be so huge to record every update. Is there any solution?

Thank you

Comment: You say 'not for log', but clearly this requirement *is* a log

Comment: If you need to store the address changes, not sure why you complain that the data can get too big! Btw, you do not necessarily have to store every address change, only store the address at the time of of adoption separately. People do not change addresses that often anyway, so your data is unlijely to get that big.

Comment: Check out MariaDB's change logging; it does the logging under the covers; you can request the data at some point in time in the past.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do sometimes:

For any field that i need to track value changes, i design a separate changes table.

For example, for the address field that is a concept associated with the user entity and is not a direct property of the adoption entity, i define the table:
UserAddressChanges(UserID, Address, ChangeDateTime, ChangerPersonID)

This way, the changes data may be used in any other sub-system or system, independent of your current adoption use-case.

---

I use in-table change tracking for very simple tables like:
UniversityManagers(PersonID, AssignDateTime, AssignorPersonID)

---

For more complex tables with frequent changes (and usually, few refers to previous data) where i need full record logging, i separate the main table (of current records) and the log table which have extra fields such as LogID, ChangeDateTime, ChangerPersonID, ChangerIP, ...

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to this.

Perhaps the simplest is to denormalize the data.  If there is data you need at the point of adoption, include it as columns in the adoption table.  This address is the "point-in-time" address.

This method is useful for simple things, but it does not scale well.  And you have to pre-define the columns you want.

The next step is to create audit tables for all your tables, or at least all tables of interest.  Every time a record changes in `user`, a new record is added into `userAudit`.  Audit tables are usually maintained using triggers.

The advantage of audit tables is that they do not clutter the existing table (and logic).  The same queries work on the existing tables.

Finally, you can just cave in and realize that your data model is overly simplified.  You really have slowly changing dimensions.  This data can be represented using version effective dates and version end dates for each row.  The user table ends up looking like:

```
user_id   name    address    version_eff_dt    version_end_dt
```

Because user_id is no longer a primary key, you might want two tables `users` and `userHistory`, or something like that.

This is a "correct" representation of the data *at any point in time*.  However, it usually requires restructuring queries because a single user appears multiple times in the table -- and `user_id` is no longer the primary key.